# How do I kill a non-running impdp job?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-sql-developer, impdp, datapump

I am trying to run an import operation into an Oracle 11G R2 database from a `.dmp` file using SQL Developer 4.1's Data Pump Import Wizard.  I set everything up with IMMEDIATE start, but then the job first said it started executing and then said it is NOT RUNNING.  The job's log file was not created, so I think it stopped upon starting, perhaps due to a bad parameter.  **How can I just delete this job altogether, so that I can start the wizard again without creating problems with a duplicate job?**

I typed `select * from SYS.DBA_DATAPUMP_JOBS;` and found the job as the only one listed:  `JOB_NAME='IMPORT_JOB_SQLDEV_46'`

And I google searched on the topic, but the only articles were many years old and did not give instructions which seem to work in modern SQL Developer.  For example, I tried the steps in this link, but [Ctrl-C does not seem to produce anything](http://blog.oracle48.nl/killing-and-resuming-datapump-expdp-and-impdp-jobs/comment-page-1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop export/import job using the following command
First of all find the name of the job table under 'DataPump>Import Jobs or Export Jobs'.

[image]

Use the drop command to drop that table by the user who has created that import/export job. In my case it was created by SYSTEM user.

```
SQL>conn system/password
SQL>DROP TABLE EXPORT_JOB_SQLDEV_41;
Table dropped.
```